# copy entire excel worksheet to a new worksheet using Python win32com

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, win32com

I try to open an existing workbook called 'N11 Result.xlsx'. Copy the entire worksheet 'Sheet1' (rename it to'Built with Python' first...) and paste to a new worksheet(named 'Annual') within the same workbook. I think the last line of my code doesn't work... any help will be helpful.

```
import os,sys
sys.path.append(r"""U:\Programming\Python\Python Manipulate Excel""")
work_dir=r"""U:\Programming\Python\Python Manipulate Excel"""
file_name='N11 Result.xlsx'

import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(work_dir+'\\'+file_name)
ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')
ws.Name = 'Built with Python'
wb.Worksheets("Built with Python").Copy(before=wb.Worksheets("Annual"))
excel.Application.Quit()
```

The error message showed up will be

*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:\Programming\Python\Python Manipulate Excel\Test_createExcel_01.py", line 17, in 
    wb.Worksheets("Built with Python").Copy(before=wb.Worksheets("Annual"))
  File "C:\Temp\gen_py\2.7\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x7\Sheets.py", line 113, in **call**
    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(0, LCID, 2, (9, 0), ((12, 1),),Index
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)*

Comment: Maybe look at one of the Python libraries for doing just this: xlwt/xlrd openpyxl, xlsxwriter, etc. In my experience this is much simpler than messing with win32com

Comment: @SiHa You are definitely right. I start using openpyxl, do you know any book or website I should check to learn more about openpyxl? thanks!

Comment: How about the official documention? https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ It's very thorough.

Answer (score 3):

So this is how you can copy an entire worksheet into a new sheet using pywin32:

```
# old_sheet: sheet that you want to copy
old_sheet.Copy(pythoncom.Empty, workbook.Sheets(workbook.Sheets.Count))
new_sheet = workbook.Sheets(workbook.Sheets.Count)
new_sheet.Name = 'Annual'
```

Comment: After I change `pythoncom.Empty` into `None`, it worked.

Thank you a lot. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
    import win32com.client as win32
    from copy import copy
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    #excel.Visible = False
    excel.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb0 = excel.Workbooks.Open(dirname + '\\' + 'original.xlsx')
    ws0 = wb0.Worksheets('Original_sheet')
    wb2 = excel.Workbooks.Open(dirname + '\\' + writer.path)
    ws2 = wb2.Worksheets.Add()
    ws2.Name = 'Copy_original'
    ws2 = wb2.Worksheets('Copy_original')
    ws0.Range("A1:AF100").Copy(ws2.Range("A%s:AF%s" % (row, col)))
    wb2.Save()
    excel.Application.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching out `wb.Worksheets("Built with Python").Copy(before=wb.Worksheets("Annual"))` with the following code.

```
wb.Worksheets("Built with Python").Cells.Select()
excel.Selection.Copy(Destination=wb.Worksheets("Annual").Range("A1"))
```

Let me know if that works. If it doesn't work it may be the directory you're trying to build that might be the cause.